# Please check my method to autheniticate mobile app with PHP server

Tags: android, security, authentication, mobile

I'm building an android app that needs to authenticate with a php service. My current approach is when the user initially logs in, a unique id is generated using uniqid(). This uid is then stored in a table on the database along with their username.The user is then passed back this uid.

Subsequently all further requests to the server will send the the uid and their username, which will be then checked in the database to authenticate the user.

Is this approach OK? or are their massive security holes that I am missing?

Comment: This isn't really a PHP question. Retagged.

Comment: this seems conceptually similar to a session cookie.  Make sure these id's expire on your server after some period of inactivity.  Ensure that all traffic is encrypted in transit.

Comment: I forgot to add that yes I will kill the token after a period of time. Do you have any advice on how to encrypt the traffic without using SSL? Is the method of just using a function such as uniqid() to generate the authentication token?

Comment: Why would you not use ssl when it is so easy?

Comment: Quite simply, cost is an issue initially

Comment: You can use openSSL free. YOu will have to store the certificate on the Android device in a keystore. Then you can create a HTTPS connection securely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems here.  For one `uniqid()` is almost entirely made up of a timestamp and there for very predictable.  Instead of just reinventing the wheel you should just use PHP's `session_start()`.  If for some reason you can't use PHP's sessions,  then generate a session id using `session_id()`.

Other problems,  if your application suffers from sql injection then an attacker can pull the session id out of the database and just login.  The reason why passwords are hashed is to slow down an attacker after the database has been compromised,  if the attacker has the session id then he doesn't have to crack a password hash to login. (You are hashing passwords right...)  One option is to use MySQL's `aes_encrypt()` on the stored session id's.

Comment: Sounds logical although I have a few questions. Can I still use php sessions, my understanding is that sessions die after a user leaves the page. Or am I session to create an token? I do hash and salt the password. Can I use this method on the token/session id rather than aes_encrypt?

Comment: @user1565982 You can configure PHP sessions to last as long as you would like,  but they should expire after a day maybe a week,  it depends on the application.  Of course you hash and salt passwords,  there are more than 10,000 posts on SO related to password storage.   You should use PHP's session handler whenever possible.  The best cryptographers avoid cryptographic systems whenever possible.

Comment: So let me get this straight, I initially send username/password to the server. The server creates a session. Then somehow I need to save this session on the mobile client. I then use this session in subsequent calls to the server. This session can be valid for a day / week / month etc. This way I no longer need to create a unique token for authentication and store it in the server?

Comment: Great! one final question regarding this method. I would like my users to only have to enter their username/password into my app once a month. Is it really safe to extend the duration of the session for so long for this kind of authentication?

Comment: @user1565982 not recommended, but probably not the biggest vulnerability in your application.

Comment: Thanks, if it is not recommended, what alternatives could be used?

Comment: @user1565982  no idea,  its probably ok to have a month long session.  The bigger vulnerability is that you almost certainly a violation OWAP a9 because you are probably transmitting this session id over HTTP.  So it doesn't matter if the session lasts 5 seconds,  users will still get hacked.